# why I am getting undefined for the (this.ingredients)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to log the ingredients to the console but it is always undefined

```
export default class Recipe {
    constructor(ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    getRicepeById () {
        const res = await fetch(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/get?key=${key}&rId=${this.ID}`);
        this.title = res.data.recipe.title;
        this.image = res.data.recipe.image_url;
        this.author = res.data.recipe.publisher;
        this.ingredients = res.data.recipe.ingredients; 
        //this.ingredients = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 23, 2];
    }

    calculateTime() {
        const totalIngredients = this.ingredients;
        //here is my problem
        console.log(totalIngredients)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do u call the function?

Comment: Hello! Please read [Question Check](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) list and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

`getRicepeById` should be `async` because you use `await` in the body of this method.
Also, make sure you are calling `calculateTime` after `fetch` completed

Answer (score 0):

and you have to read the fetched data as follow :

```js
class Recipe {
    constructor(ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    async getRecipeById () {
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/jta0q`);
        res.json().then(data => {
            this.ingredients = data;
            this.calculateTime();
        });
    }

    calculateTime() {
        const totalIngredients = this.ingredients;
        console.log(totalIngredients)
    }
}

let recipe = new Recipe();
recipe.getRecipeById();
```